# combine two select queries from the same mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

We have a table of users with column membership_end which is, as the name say - the date when users membership end. Now some users never purchase membership so that field is empty. For some users, that field is in the past (membership expired).
What I need is to sort the active members first (ordered by the membership_end date desc), then the rest of the users in some independent sorting order. Basically we need to show active members on top.

```
SELECT * FROM accounts where membership_end>=now() 
order by membership_end desc
union
???
```

- Should we use union or something else?
- What would be a second query to avoid duplicates?

Thanks in advance

Ok, to clear things up a bit.

```
SELECT * FROM accounts where membership_end>=now()
order by membership_end desc
```

gives us 12 active members and this is fine. we then have this:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts where membership_end<now()
order by id desc
```

we simply need to combine these two in one query. that's all.

EDIT:
Actually i figured it out. It's quite simple.

SELECT id, membership_end
FROM accounts
ORDER BY membership_end >= NOW( ) DESC , id DESC

no unions. no complicated queries :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can sort null values to be first, so you could avoid unions :

```
SELECT membership_end FROM accounts 
where membership_end>=now() or membership_end is null 
ORDER BY [membership_end] IS NULL DESC, [membership_end] DESC
```

Comment: Hi there, that will not show users whose membership_end is not null (for instance those whose membership_end is 6/6/2016

Comment: Indeed, it was your query provided in the question : `membership_end>=now()`. I just wanted to emphasize that you could select null values and sort them

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want duplicates I would recommend to do this. I don't know what condition you want to use to filter members with null membership_end filed but if all I would do something like that:

```
SELECT membership_end FROM accounts where membership_end>=now() or membership_end is null order by membership_end desc
```

Descending ordering should put members with null membership_end in the end of list so you may want to add additional ordering.

Comment: nah, please read above. again you're leaving out those with expired memberships. so basibally first query should be those with membership_end in the future, the second should be all other users sorted in descending id order

Comment: @outlaw I've been trying to figure out why you needed a union at all for an hour -  you should edit your question to include 'the second should be all users sorted in descending id order'

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT membership_end FROM table1 where membership_end>=now() 
Union all
SELECT membership_end FROM table2 where membership_end>=now()
```

this will combine table1 and table2

The important bit is 1 field for table1 and 1 field for table2 only. It must be the same.

Comment: No matter what table is it..it is possibly done. Even just only one table. just explain what result do you want to be.. so that i can help you..

Comment: @Draken your answer confuse me. The question indicated only one table, here your answer contains 'table1', 'table2'. And why all conditions of the 2 SELECT queries  are 'membership_end>=now()'.

Comment: It's not my answer @EkeymeMo, I just edited it to look nicer. You need to speak to Reds instead

Comment: Its just an example that two possible queries possibly combine. regardless what table is it..

Comment: @reds That's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two tricks here 1) associate ids with dates by creating a combined date + id field, historic and nulls have been given a seed date in the future to avoid overlaps with future dated members (you may wish to push this out) 2) allocate a srce number to the unioned statements.

```
/*
create table m (id int, enddte date);
truncate table m;
insert into m values
(1,null),(2,'2016-10-01'),(3,'2016-11-10'),(4,'2016-02-01'),(5,'2016-03-01'),(6,null);
*/
select * from
(
select  1 as srce,m.id,m.enddte ,
         year(m.enddte) * 10000 + month(m.enddte) * 100 + m.id as uniqueid
from        m
where       m.enddte >= now()

) s
union
(
select  2,id,enddte,
            year(cast('2050-01-01'  as date)) * 10000 + month(cast('2050-01-01'  as date)) * 100  + id
from        m
where       m.enddte < now() or m.enddte is null

) 

order       by srce,uniqueid desc
```

or you could do this without a union

```
select  * from
(
select  case 
            when enddte >= now() then 1
            else 2
            end as srce,
          id, enddte,
          case 
            when enddte >= now() then  year(m.enddte) * 10000 + month(m.enddte) * 100 + m.id 
            else    year(cast('2050-01-01'  as date)) * 10000 + month(cast('2050-01-01'  as date)) * 100  + id
            end as uniqueid
from        m
) s order       by srce,uniqueid desc
```